# Does paging JPA have same order each request

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I use JPA to get page result from DB

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from Table");
int pageNumber = 6;
int pageSize = 10;
query.setFirstResult((pageNumber-1) * pageSize); 
query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List <Foo> fooList = query.getResultList();
```

I have question, does result in page x (ex:6) always same items each request?
I tested it have same result a page each request but I'm not sure.
If I use "ORDER BY" I think is same but I'm not sure if not have "ORDER BY" in native query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `ORDER BY` clause the order of the select statement is undefined. It can be ordered by `ID` or other column due to an index defined. But you have no guarantee it will remain the same with each call.

The only guarantee of having a defined order is by adding `ORDER BY` clause.

This is not related to `JPA`. It is just pure `SQL` specification.